# How to optimize this further (speed first, then memory)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization

I have this small code that takes an object and convert it to a byte[].
Using C# 4.0.
Can I optimize this further regarding speed then memory usage?
Even small changes would be great - calling this several thousand times+ per second.

```
    public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        using (ms)
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);  
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: What types of objects are we talking about?  And is the BinaryFormatter format a requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that BinaryFormatter is using reflection to read the fields of your objects. Assume you have a simple class with 1 field:

```
[Serializable]
public class Test
{
    public int A;
}
```

If you serialize an array of those using BinaryFormatter, it will do something like that for each instance of Test:

```
int val = (int)typeof(Test).GetField("A").GetValue(obj);
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(val);
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

The calls to GetField() will consume quite a lot of time.
You can significantly improve the speed using 3 ways:

1. Serialize everything manually. Something similar to this code:

   ```
   void SimpleSerialize(Stream stream, Test[] arr)
   {
       foreach (var obj in arr)
       {
           var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(obj.A);
           stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Generate a custom serialization class on-the-fly using Reflection.Emit functionality. This is more generic and "clean", but requires a lot of effort.
3. If you're fine with it, use some third-party [serializer](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.100000-times.2010-08-17.html) that suits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to optimize this further, the first thing you need to know is where you are currently spending the most time.  Did you run this through a profiler?  What were the results?

I would also ask myself "what concrete benefits will optimizing this provide to my users?".  In other words, am I optimizing this because, as an Engineer, I want to perfect the code or because it will provide a real benefit to the people I'm delivering the solution to?

I suspect that you are spending most of your time performing the actual serialization,  Changing to a different serializer will likely produce the most benefit.  See the following question for alternative, faster serializers:

[Fast and compact object serialization in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549128/fast-and-compact-object-serialization-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

There's really not much you could do to improve this code. If you are dealing with simple objects you could improve this code by replacing the [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) with a [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) and manually serializing each field/property which would be the fastest serialization you could get. But that's an extreme measure you should take only if you have experimentally determined that this code is somehow a bottleneck for your application. Otherwise you might be wasting your time doing micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Define a [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) `byte[]` as an instance field and use it as a cache. Wrap your memory stream around this cache object. When you use `MemoryStream` as written in your code, you will be performing tons of allocation, re-allocation, and array copying steps, as `MemoryStream` will be resizable. There is also the cost of garbage collection to consider.

Possibly, though I'm not sure how well this will work, cache both your formatting objects as `ThreadStatic` instance fields.

PS, I'm sure it's a mistake, but notice that you're disposing of the `MemoryStream` before using it.