# Is it possible to compress a List<Type> in .net?

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-parsing, compression, gzip

I currently have a web-serice running, returning calls to an iPhone client that i've built. The web-service is returning xml in the form of soap.

What we've noticed is that when we use a specific function, the call takes longer than accepted in terms of UX.

Here is some example code and sample xml

**Function**

```
public List<Foo> bar(....)
{

    // stuff


    return Bar;  
}
```

Where the result is serialized to XML and consumed in the iPhone client.

**Example of XML returned by the function.** ( this xml can grow very large depending on how the user uses the client application).

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <response xmlns="uri:Foo">
      <result>
        <p>
          <num>string</num>
          <d>int</d>
          <pf>string</pf>
          <pt>string</pt>
          <ipk>boolean</ipk>
          <ipa>boolean</ipa>
          <va>
            <ava xsi:nil="true" />
            <ava xsi:nil="true" />
          </va>
          <dps>
            <dp xsi:nil="true" />
            <dp xsi:nil="true" />
          </dps>
          <dst>string</dst>
        </p>
      </result>
    </response>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What i basically want is to make the data smaller. Preferably by some sort of compression.

Is it possible to compress the size of the XML before returning it to the iPhone client?

I looked at [gzip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx), but couldnt really get any grip of it, since it works with streams.

Any tips and/or pointers will be highly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can exchange the serialization i would look into this topic:
[Fast and compact object serialization in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549128/fast-and-compact-object-serialization-in-net)

Of course you can also use compression if you don't want to loose the xml format:

- http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html Has a C# SDK
- http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

Answer (score 1):

TIPS / Pointers:

1. Consider using JSON if possible, it has a smaller footprint.
2. Look into using [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) class
3. Here is an article on [string compression / encryption](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27396/Easy-String-Compression-and-Encryption)

Answer (score 1):

What about using [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx)? That way you could return your data as a compressed byte array rather than XML. I used this approach for saving XML segments in memory to keep the footprint down and it shaved roughly 80% off the overall size e.g.

**Compress at server**

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zip = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        xmlDoc.Save(zip, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
    }
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

**Decompress at client**

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(compressedBytes))
{
    using (var zip = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        return XDocument.Load(zip);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF 4.5 or higher you can use compression on the binary encoder:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Enable compression on the webserver as a start. That way you don't have concerns on compressing it manualy and as an added benefit all content (besides img's) will get compressed resulting in an overal better experience.

I doubt however if it will really solve the problem since you mentioned that the data grows large. Perhaps an idea to invent a different scheme with caching on the client and requesting just the delta's when needed (or in the background).

Something harder to do but will help you on the long term in my opinion