# Simple User configurable settings file

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Im looking for a way to allow users to change settings for a C# console application, in a simple way. I only wanna present them with a key:value pair, where they can then change the value.

I have only been able to find solutions, where a lot more information is presented to the user. Things that might confuse them or things I don't want them to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Serializable]
public class SettingItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

private List<SettingItem> ProjSettings = new List<SettingItem>();
ProjSettings.Add(new SettingItem {Name = "SomeKey", "SomeValue"});
```

You can then save/load the to and from xml files.

Comment: This approach will not be limited to just XML files (which might not be what Mikkel originally asked for), but any serializer can be used (e.g., see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549128/fast-and-compact-object-serialization-in-net) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your own config file, and let users change settings by opening that file in notepad. Otherwise, you can provide them interface. Something like YourAppName.config in application directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using , an applicaiton.exe.config then you can use something code similar to this .

In below code example  - you have to make changes accordingly

```
   ArrayList keysArrList = new ArrayList();
            keysArrList.AddRange(hashConfigTable.Keys);
            keysArrList.Sort();
         //Get the application configuration file.
                    System.Configuration.Configuration config =
                                ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

                    if (filepath.Length > 0)
                    {
                        System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                        configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = filepath;

                        config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                    }


                ConfigurationSectionGroup mySectiongrp = config.GetSectionGroup("IF ANY GROUP PRESENT IN CONFIG FILE");
                ConfigurationSection mySection = mySectiongrp.Sections[sFormatClassName];



                foreach (Object okey in keysArrList)
                {
                    XmlNode node = GetNodeAvailable(document, okey.ToString());

                    XmlAttributeCollection attrcoll = node.Attributes;

                    foreach (XmlAttribute attr in attrcoll)
                    {                   
                        if ( String.Equals(attr.Name ,"VALUE",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            XmlComment newComment;
                            newComment = document.CreateComment(string.Format(" Modified by Batch WinConsole Version:{0} on Date:{1} PREVIOUS_VALUE:{2}  By:{3}", m_sFileVersion, DateTime.Now, attr.Value,System.Environment.UserName));

                            XmlElement element = attr.OwnerElement;
                            element.AppendChild(newComment);
                            attr.Value = Convert.ToString(hashConfigTable[okey]);
                        }
                    }
                }


    mySection.SectionInformation.SetRawXml(document.OuterXml);


                //Before save take a backup
                FileSystemUtil fsutil = new FileSystemUtil();
                string sNewfilename=string.Format("{0}_{1}.config",Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMMdd_hhmmss"));
                fsutil.FileCopy(filepath, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath), "Backup", "config", sNewfilename));


                //final Save
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sFormatClassName);
```